# Creating RestApi without using rails only using Rack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rack

i have to create a rest api using grape [link](https://github.com/intridea/grape/wiki).in the rest api i don't want to use Rails gem it can be created using simply gem.

1. My first question is this a good approach for making application light .
2. How to create a Model or database Object using only rake in rails if i have to create a User Model then i use this command

   ```
   rails generate model User name:string email:string
   ```

what is the alternative when i am using only Rack. please provide some helpful link for creating database apps using only rails. i have to use postgresql!!

Comment: If you don't want to use rails, then you usually need to manually create your models and files by hand

Comment: any example or link of creating model by hand or link please provide

Comment: yes apology for that mistyping.i mean Rack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grape is great for REST APIs. It does not build models for you.

Are you using a database, such as sqlite, mysql, postgres, etc.?

I really like the "sequel" gem for database connections.

This is good info from the sequel page:

```
require "rubygems"
require "sequel"

# connect to an in-memory database
DB = Sequel.sqlite

# create an items table
DB.create_table :items do
  primary_key :id
  String :name
  Float :price
end

# create a dataset from the items table
items = DB[:items]

# populate the table
items.insert(:name => 'abc', :price => 100)
items.insert(:name => 'def', :price => 120)
items.insert(:name => 'ghi', :price => 150)

# print out the number of records
puts "Item count: #{items.count}"

# print out the average price
puts "The average price is: #{items.avg(:price)}"
```

For more on sequel see http://sequel.rubyforge.org/